# Jest failing when comparing result of toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to test a method that uses `toLocaleString`, but when comparing the result jest I get an error `Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality` failing for the whitespaces between the currency symbol and the number.

[image]

I already tried comparing to `&nbsp;` between them and replacing the `€` by `&euro;`entity, but with no success. Do you have an idea what the solution might be?

My test:

```
describe('Test getFormattedCurrencyString', () => {
    test('should convert number to currency string', () => {

        const testInt = 23799.99;
        const result = testInt.toLocaleString('de-DE', {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'EUR',
            minimumFractionDigits: 2,
            maximumFractionDigits: 2,
        });

        expect('23.799,99 €').toBe(result);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand what the problem is you can try

```
result.charCodeAt(9); // 160
```

which is an UTF "Non-breaking space", you can just copy the result from your console and paste it into the unit test.

**Edit** as future reminder you can add an assertion

```
expect(result.charCodeAt(9)).toBe(160)
```